# Resolving dependency in Angular2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I wondering in Angular 2 if there is a way in angular2 to resolve dependency without going to constructor.  In .net you can inject dependency in 3 ways (Constructor, setter, interface-based).  Can I also do a setter injection on angular2 ts.

Answer (score 2):

Angular2 only supports constructor injection.

A workaround that might work for you, is to inject an `Injector` and get dependencies imperatively

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) {
  this.xxx = injector.get(SomeType);
}
```